# Como dropar elemento Draggable somente em divs Droppable e não dropar no resto da tela

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, resize, ui-draggable

Fala galera, estou com um probleminha aqui, deixei de utilizar o `**Drag and Drop**` nativo do HTML5 por que o mesmo não dá suporte aos navegadores Android, passei a utilizar então o **JqueryUi**.
Tenho alguns gráficos do *Google Chart* `Draggable` que deveriam ficar presos nas `divs Droppable`, no exemplo a seguir "DropZone1 e DropZone2":

**HTML**:

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
</div>

<div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content">
</div>

<div id="droppable1" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop Zone 1</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable2" class="droppable ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop Zone 2</p>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$( function() {
    $( "#draggable, #draggable2" ).draggable({

      });
    $( ".droppable" ).droppable({
      accept: '#draggable, #draggable2', 
        drop :function(event, ui ) {
          var largura =  $(this).css("width");
          var altura =  $(this).css("height");
          var esquerda =  $(this).offset().left;
          var topo =  $(this).offset().top;
          $(ui.draggable).css("width", largura);
          $(ui.draggable).css("height", altura);
          $(ui.draggable).css("left", esquerda); 
          $(ui.draggable).css("top", topo); 
          drawBasic();
          drawChart();
      }
    }).resizable({
      resize: function( event, ui ) {
          var largura =  $(this).css("width");
          var altura =  $(this).css("height");
          var esquerda =  $(this).offset().left;
          var topo =  $(this).offset().top;
          $(ui.draggable).css("width", largura);
          $(ui.draggable).css("height", altura);
          $(ui.draggable).css("left", esquerda); 
          $(ui.draggable).css("top", topo); 
          drawBasic();
          drawChart();
      }
    });
  } );



google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawBasic() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');

      data.addRows([
        [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '8 am'}, 1],
        [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '9 am'}, 2],
        [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'10 am'}, 3],
        [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '11 am'}, 4],
        [{v: [12, 0, 0], f: '12 pm'}, 5],
        [{v: [13, 0, 0], f: '1 pm'}, 6],
        [{v: [14, 0, 0], f: '2 pm'}, 7],
        [{v: [15, 0, 0], f: '3 pm'}, 8],
        [{v: [16, 0, 0], f: '4 pm'}, 9],
        [{v: [17, 0, 0], f: '5 pm'}, 10],
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Motivation Level Throughout the Day',
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time of Day',
          format: 'h:mm a',
          viewWindow: {
            min: [7, 30, 0],
            max: [17, 30, 0]
          }
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Rating (scale of 1-10)'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
        document.getElementById('draggable'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('draggable2'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

Gostaria de poder intercalar os gráficos entre as `DIV droppable`, por exemplo, o `draggable` quando for arrastado da `droppable1` para a `droppable2` o `draggable2` sai da `droppable2` e vai pro lugar do `draggable`.

O resultado que quero é algo como apresentado neste exemplo: https://codepen.io/jo-o-santos/pen/aPKgoQ

> Segue Exemplo Funcional do meu cenário atual:
>   https://codepen.io/jo-o-santos/pen/zyaXLK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, consegui resolver o meu problema utilizando `Sortable` no lugar de `Draggable`, segue o link com a minha solução:

> https://codepen.io/jo-o-santos/pen/rorEoo